# Terraform throwing error, "No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider" on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I started learning Terraform. I am now trying to deploy an EC2 instance to the AWS following the tutorial. I am using Windows 10. I have configured the AWS credentials on my laptop and I have been using it to deploy my applications to the ElasticBeanstalk. But it seems not to be working with Terraform.

I have an example.tf file with the following code.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 2.70"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-west-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-830c94e3"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

To deploy, I have run the following command.

```
terraform apply
```

Then I got the following error.

```
Error: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
        Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
        providing credentials for the AWS Provider
```

Instead of using profile, when I use, acess_key and access_secret, it is working as expected. But there are AWS credentials already configured on my machine. I cannot just figure out why it is not working. What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

This is my ~/.aws/config file.

[image]

This is my ~/.aws/credentials file.

[image]

Comment: Does you have a credentials file with a `default` section?

Comment: Yes. It does. In both config and credentials files.

Comment: Where is the credentials file located?

Comment: ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config. I am using git bash terminal.

Comment: Could you include your credentials file with the secrets obfuscated?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question to include the screenshots. Please, have a  look.